# Angular html5 mode with Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, html5mode

I'm deploying my Angular 7 app on Google Cloud (App Engine).

The app is working fine, but I've some questions...

First of all is how to handle html5 mode, so that when I'm on a route (e.g https://myapp.com/my-route/) and I refresh the browser, the server should reply my the index.html, and the angular should perform the routing, instead of returning a 404 error page.

How can I do that? Can you help me?

Thanks so much!

Comment: could you share you're app.yaml ?

Comment: yes @ThierryFalvo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my app.yaml, it's working fine, if you have any tips please share :)

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true

skip_files:
- ^(?!dist)

handlers:
- url: /en/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)(|\.map))$
  static_files: dist/en/\1
  upload: dist/en/(.*)(|\.map)

- url: /it/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)(|\.map))$
  static_files: dist/it/\1
  upload: dist/it/(.*)(|\.map)

- url: /en/(.*)
  static_files: dist/en/index.html
  upload: dist/en/index.html

- url: /it/(.*)
  static_files: dist/it/index.html
  upload: dist/it/index.html

- url: /
  static_files: dist/en/index.html
  upload: dist/en/index.html

error_handlers:
- file: index.html
```